# How to build dash with CMake?

Tags: cmake, dash-shell

I'm trying to build [dash](ftp://ftp.tuwien.ac.at/.vhost/www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/postlfs/dash.html) using Clion and CMake but I get this build error:

```
/opt/clion-2016.1.1/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/dac/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/dash-46b33cad/46b33cad/Debug --target all -- -j 4
[  3%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/error.c.o
[  6%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/eval.c.o
[  9%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/cd.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/arith_yylex.c.o
In file included from /home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/error.c:54:0:
/home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/system.h:65:22: error: static declaration of ‘strtod’ follows non-static declaration
 static inline double strtod(const char *nptr, char **endptr)
                      ^
In file included from /home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/error.c:40:0:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:164:15: note: previous declaration of ‘strtod’ was here
 extern double strtod (const char *__restrict __nptr,
               ^
In file included from /home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/error.c:54:0:
/home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/system.h:86:19: error: static declaration of ‘killpg’ follows non-static declaration
 static inline int killpg(pid_t pid, int signal)
                   ^
In file included from /home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/error.c:39:0:
/usr/include/signal.h:134:12: note: previous declaration of ‘killpg’ was here
 extern int killpg (__pid_t __pgrp, int __sig) __THROW;
            ^
In file included from /home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/error.c:54:0:
/home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/system.h:97:0: warning: "_SC_CLK_TCK" redefined
 #define _SC_CLK_TCK 2
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:609:0,
                 from /home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/error.c:42:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/confname.h:78:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define _SC_CLK_TCK   _SC_CLK_TCK
 ^
CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:182: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main.dir/error.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/error.c.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/eval.c:51:22: fatal error: builtins.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/arith_yylex.c:44:0:
/home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/system.h:65:22: error: static declaration of ‘strtod’ follows non-static declaration
 static inline double strtod(const char *nptr, char **endptr)
                      ^
In file included from /home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/arith_yylex.c:36:0:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:164:15: note: previous declaration of ‘strtod’ was here
 extern double strtod (const char *__restrict __nptr,
               ^
In file included from /home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/arith_yylex.c:44:0:
/home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/system.h:86:19: error: static declaration of ‘killpg’ follows non-static declaration
 static inline int killpg(pid_t pid, int signal)
                   ^
In file included from /home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/error.h:38:0,
                 from /home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/arith_yylex.c:40:
/usr/include/signal.h:134:12: note: previous declaration of ‘killpg’ was here
 extern int killpg (__pid_t __pgrp, int __sig) __THROW;
            ^
In file included from /home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/syntax.h:5:0,
                 from /home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/arith_yylex.c:43:
/home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/system.h:102:17: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘c’
 int isblank(int c);
                 ^
/home/dac/Downloads/dash-0.5.8/dash/system.h:102:5: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
 int isblank(int c);
     ^
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:206: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main.dir/eval.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/eval.c.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:134: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main.dir/arith_yylex.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/arith_yylex.c.o] Error 1
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (dash)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -include config.h -DBSD=1 -DSHELL -DIFS_BROKEN")
add_executable(main main.c alias.c arith_yacc.c arith_yylex.c cd.c error.c eval.c exec.c expand.c histedit.c input.c jobs.c mail.c main.c memalloc.c miscbltin.c mystring.c options.c parser.c redir.c show.c trap.c output.c bltin/printf.c system.c bltin/test.c bltin/times.c var.c alias.h arith_yacc.h bltin/bltin.h cd.h error.h eval.h exec.h expand.h hetio.h init.h input.h jobs.h machdep.h mail.h main.h memalloc.h miscbltin.h myhistedit.h mystring.h options.h output.h parser.h redir.h shell.h show.h system.h trap.h var.h mktokens mkbuiltins builtins.def.in mkinit.c mknodes.c nodetypes nodes.c.pat mksyntax.c mksignames.c)
```

What can I do to make it build? If I use the makefile and build with make then it builds. But I want to build with CMake.

Comment: Looks like you use improper configuration options. Compare compile line for make after `./configure` and after `cmake`.

Comment: Use `make VERBOSE=1` after CMake and check actual compiler flags with those used after `./configure`. I guess, the difference is there.